# ER Diagram - Choose One or Both of the Entities

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams

So I am attempting to create an ER Digram for a certain catering service. Two of the entities are "Lunch Menu" and "Dinner Menu". Each catering reservation (entity) must contain either one of the two, or both.

How should I go about modelling this relationship?

Comment: What is different about these menus and how is this information going to be used? Will you ever need to cater breakfast, brunch, lunch, dinner, and supper? You need to give us use cases, edge cases, and some concept of your goals if we're to help you.

Comment: Why not just "Menu" with a type?

Comment: @Erik There will only ever be catering for lunch and dinner. Customers make a reservation which holds information such as party size, date, etc. but also needs reference to a lunch menu or dinner menu. All reservations must have a lunch or dinner plan or both. These lunch and dinner plans have attributes such as server, number of guests, menu. The menu must have attributes such as the foods. My goal is to try and link this "Lunch Menu" and "Dinner Menu" to the "Reservation" where Reservation has FK of these menus. I need to model the Reservation linking to at least lunch, dinner or both.

Comment: so far I can see a minimum of four tables. 1) Profile of entity making the reservation, 2) Reservations table, 3) Menu table, 4) Food table. Please add the information in your comment into your question, and try to add anything more that might be relevant. We can't really offer a solution that fits your needs without knowing what you need fully.